# Filter once or filter multiple times

Tags: javascript, algorithm, code-complexity

I have an array with objects:

```
objects = [a, b, c, ...]
```

I have a number of functions which returns true/false for a given object

```
functions = [f1, f2, f3, ...]
```

Now I want to get all the objects which passes all functions. What's most efficient?

```
functions.forEach(function(f) {
       objects = objects.filter(f);
})
```

OR

```
objects = objects.filter(function(o) {
       functions.forEach(function(f) {
            if(!f(o)) return false;
       })
})
```

I'm not sure what's most effecient, it depends on how heavy the filter function is? Are they the same?

Comment: The complexity should be the same. The difference is only on interaction of HW architecture and algorithm implementation. That is dependent on platform which you did not specify. Anyway the only way to know for sure is measure and choose the better option on your platform.

Comment: Thanks, it's client side code for a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little test:

```
  console.time("Creating objects");
  var objects1 = [];
  var objects2 = [];
  while (objects1.length < 20000) {
    var value = 1000 * Math.random();
    objects1.push({ value: value });
    objects2.push({ value: value });
  }
  console.timeEnd("Creating objects");

  console.time("Creating functions")
  var functions = [];
  while (functions.length < 1000) {
    var rnd_value = 1000 * Math.random();
    functions.push(function(o) {
        return o.value >= rnd_value;
    });
  }
  console.timeEnd("Creating functions")

  console.time("Functions outer")

  functions.forEach(function(f) {
    objects1 = objects1.filter(f);
  });

  console.timeEnd("Functions outer");

  console.time("Filter outer")

  objects2 = objects2.filter(function(o) {
    var ret = true;
    functions.forEach(function(f) {
      if (ret && !f(o)) ret = false;
    });
    return ret;
  });

  console.timeEnd("Filter outer");
```

The result in console was:
    Functions outer: 3188.918ms
    Filter outer: 454.249ms

So I assume the filter function on array is pretty heavy in javascript. In other word, I should call it as few times as possible.

Comment: `filter` creates a new array each time it is called. However, unless this is a bottleneck in your code, just do what's simplest.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you call `objects.filter` for each function, the complexities are the same. You can optimize a little bit if you use `filter` on the result of previous filter instead of applying it on all objects every time.

```
for (f in functions){
    objects = objects.filter(functions[f])
}
```

If possible, sort your function by time complexity *times* their probability to return True (ascending).

Comment: The additional conditions could even slow things down as I mentioned before depends on platform and algorithms implementation. But as it is a client side of WEB page and if the filters run on server side and call sequence on client side then this should improve performance